# Why $_POST is empty when using [QSA] in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post, qsa

I've got the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.htm)$ index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Everyting works great but result URLs have empty $_POST.

I'm 100% sure that it's mod_rewrite bug, not HTML or PHP because when I change [QSA,L] to [L] it works great. But I really need QSA.

It happens at about 30% hostings so this may be some Apache config option.

Comment: Can you check to see if anything is available in $_REQUEST (which includes $_GET and $_POST) - I'm curious to see if your $_POST values are transforming into $_GET values...

Comment: Yes, I've checked. $_REQUEST is filled with $_GET values only

Comment: the thing which puzzled me a few times in the query is the $0 instead of $1

Answer (score 0):

What about modifying your rule in this way. Does it change anything?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ index.php?url=$0.htm [QSA,L]
```

Comment: strange. Is there a variation between servers depending on the server version? Or does it happen randomly?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly this issue.  It works on one server then not the next.  Annoying and time consuming to say the least!

After a lot of checking using this php:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST AS $key => $value) echo $value."<br>";
```

at the top of the index.php to check what values were being sent from the htaccess file, (and many other checks I will not go into!) I eventually found you need to specify  "RewriteBase"

Adding `RewriteBase /` to the top of the htaccess file made it work on the all the servers I tried.

(also, remember to set to:  `RewriteBase /folder-where-file-is/`
where "folder-where-file-is" is the location of the index.php file if in a sub-folder)

Hope it helps you - knowing this would certainly have helped me many many hours ago!

Comment: This is not a solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

by default,.. maybe apache not enable mod_rewrite, try type this on your console

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

sample my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. The problem is that the POST parameter get lost when using [QSA].